# Stored Procedure Redirect logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

We are developing an application where sometime we need to support more than one versions of that software at a time. For example Release 1-0-300 , 1-0-300-With-Test-FunctionalityA, Release 1-0-300-With-Test-FunctionalityB. Due to such requirements we sometime use the same Stored Procedure with different name in different versions for example

"**1-0-300**" uses Stored Procedures "**USP_GetProucts**"

"**1-0-300-With-Test-FunctionalityA**" uses Stored Procedures "**USP_GetProucts_FunctionalityA**"

"**1-0-300-With-Test-FunctionalityB**" uses Stored Procedures "**USP_GetProucts_FunctionalityB**"

**Some Facts**:

1- Why we are not using some alternate solution like we can have a Parameter "WhichStoredProcedureToCall" based on that parameter we can call the required STored Procedure?
Because "USP_GetProucts" can have total different functionality than "USP_GetProucts_FunctionalityA" & these are huge stored procedures.

2- We are using SQL2008.

So my question is can we implement some type of "**Stored Procedure Redirect**", if "USP_GetProucts_FunctionalityA" not found then get the results form "USP_GetProucts"

Regards.

Comment: I don't understand your scenario. Why would the application be calling `USP_GetProucts_FunctionalityA` if that didn't exist until a later version? And if you are deploying changes to the database to do this redirect why not just update the schema at the same time? You might want  to look at synonyms anyway.

Comment: We are supporting the 3 releases at the same time, they can be release at the same day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if a `stored procedure` exists acessing to the `sysobjects table`:

```
IF EXISTS(select name from sysobjects where type = 'P' and name = 'tablename')
  BEGIN
     select 1
  END
```

Then you simply need to make the necessary `IF`'s.

---

Since you are using `SQL Server`, you could have a look into [`SINONYMS`](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/07/sql-server-2005-introduction-and-explanation-to-synonym-helpful-t-sql-feature-for-developer/).

You could make `USP_GetProucts`, `USP_GetProucts_FunctionalityA` and `USP_GetProucts_FunctionalityB` sinomyns :)

Comment: & for that IF i need another stored procedure??

Comment: You means i can have a StoredProcedureHandleMissingProcedure & that procedure should handle the calls to other procedures?

Comment: Great thanks, but i am looking for best practice, followed in such conditions.
+1 for this solution

Comment: @YaqubAhmad I've edit and put another solution, maybe is the best for you. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

If you use USP_GetProducts as base procedure, you could just check inside, if the stored procedure is available:

```
select name from sys.objects where type = 'P'
```

Then you can check, if your procedure is available and call it or call something different if not.